# How to find out everything that is affected by a master key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, encryption

Following up after [a situation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/238525/22336) on an important `LIVE` server -

where I have [the master key backed up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/238499/22336),

[but](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52763/22336) the decryption password for that master key backup file **is missing**.

[I can't open the master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
```

[I can't restore the master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
RESTORE MASTER KEY FROM FILE = 'path_to_file'   
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'  
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'  
    [ FORCE ]
```

What I am left with is [to regenerate the master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'dsjdkflJ435907NnmM#sX003';
GO
```

Before doing that, however,

I did some tests, like the one below:

[image]

**what I want to do is:**

1. find out everything that is affected my the master key
2. script object definitions, save the data
3. drop or regenerate the master key
4. re-create or alter any object definitions (including their permissions)
5. import back all data

Basically I want to backup everything affected by the master key, then regenerate it and then re-apply all the affected things back to the database

when I run the following queries I don't get any results:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    select * from sys.master_key_passwords ;
    select * from sys.asymmetric_keys ;
    select * from sys.crypt_properties ;
    select * from sys.credentials ;
```

when I run these ones though, I get results:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    select * from sys.certificates ;
    select * from sys.key_encryptions ;
    select * from sys.symmetric_keys ;
```

[image]

I [cannot even add the database to the availability group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/169495/22336), without sorting the master key first.

how can I find anything dependent on the master key?

Comment: Question: 1) I thought we discussed there were no secrets so the DMK could be dropped? 2) If you don't know the actual password and you're not running it on the original server, regenerate will orphan secrets. 3) If you don't care about #2, why not just do #1?